# a map with same key and value pairs

Tags: groovy

I have a record as

```
firstRecord = [ [ name1:'value1', name2:'value2', name3:'value3'],
                [ name1:'value1', name2:'value4', name3:'value5' ] ]
```

I pulled a list for having the values against name1 as

```
valueList = [ 'value1', 'value1' ]
```

I have another map

```
secondRecord = [ value1:[ key1:'value9', key2:'value10' ] ]
```

I tried looping through `valueList` and `secondRecord.subMap( [ value1.toString() ] )`

I got a map as

```
[ value1: [ key1:'value9', key2:'value10' ] ]
```

I wanted a map as below (as there are two same values in the `valueList`, I would like to have two keys with the same values)

```
requiredMap = [ value1:[ key1:'value9', key2:'value10'],
                value1:[ key1:'value9', key2:'value10' ] ]
```

but as it is a map, the second one overwrites the first one and I would be left with only one key/value pair.

Is this achievable with **Groovy 1.5.6**?

Comment: Again with the invalid groovy code... ;-)

Comment: Invalid groovy code. Why do you need to have both? You can group by their count.

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't really help, and isn't much fun of an evening

Comment: all my maps are defined as def, so I thought its good to provide the logs output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given:

```
firstRecord = [ [ name1:'value1', name2:'value2', name3:'value3'],
                [ name1:'value1', name2:'value4', name3:'value5' ] ]
```

You can get `valueList` via:

```
valueList = firstRecord.name1
```

Then, given `secondRecord`:

```
secondRecord = [ value1:[ key1:'value9', key2:'value10' ] ]
```

You can do:

```
result = valueList.inject( [:].withDefault { [] } ) { m, v ->
    m[ v ] << secondRecord[ v ]
    m
}
```

Giving:

```
assert result == [ value1:[ [ key1:'value9', key2:'value10'],
                            [ key1:'value9', key2:'value10' ] ] ]
```

---

With groovy **1.5.6**, you need to do:

```
result = valueList.inject( [:] ) { m, v ->
    if( !m[ v ] ) {
        m[ v ] = []
    }
    m[ v ] << secondRecord[ v ]
    m
}
```

Comment: @Techie no matter, I found it.  Updated answer

Comment: Hi Tim, am getting[value1:[null,null]

Comment: Running the above code?  I have it sat here in the groovy 1.5.6 console, and it works fine... I guess you're using Groovy Strings for the map keys in `secondRecord`?

Comment: but this is not serving my purpose...in my customized tool, I do need to send the key/value pair as [ value1:[ key1:'value9', key2:'value10'],value1:[ key1:'value9', key2:'value10' ] ]. may be I need to override hashcode and equals in doing that?

Comment: You can't.  That's the point of maps.  You can't have multiple identical keys in a Map. You could send it as a List of Maps? `[ [ value1:[ key1:'value9', key2:'value10'] ], [ value1:[ key1:'value9', key2:'value10'] ] ]`

Comment: Thanks for the responses Tim(though I havent got what I wanted), i know I am trying something against the basics...hmmmm